# pandas str extract as integer

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(['A1', 'B2', '3C'])
```

I want to extract the numeric portion of each element.
I know I can use `extract` in the following way

```
s.str.extract('(\d)', expand=False)

0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: object
```

Notice the `dtype: object`
If I get the `type` of each element

```
s.str.extract('(\d)', expand=False).apply(type)

0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

***question***
How do I extract directly to integer?

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this already, but you'd need to cast again using `astype(int)` or use `to_numeric` I don't think the job of `str.extract` would be to infer the dtype of the extracted groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is impossible.

See docs [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

> Returns:
>
> DataFrame with one row for each subject string, and one column for 
>   each group. Any capture group names in regular expression pat will 
>   be used for column names; otherwise capture group numbers will be 
>   used. The **dtype of each result column is always object**, even when 
>   no match is found. If expand=True and pat has only one capture group, then return a Series (if subject is a Series) or Index (if subject 
>   is an Index).

So need `astype(int)` or if `NaN` in output - [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) `pd.to_numeric(s.str.extract('(\d)', expand=False))`